# How to set radio button value the same as another radio button onclick automatically

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have two radio buttons on form for user to click just one of them ..
How can I set the another radio button value onclick action of the 1st radio action ?

```
<input type="radio" id="Male" onclick= " ">
<input type="radio" id="AltMale" >
```

Comment: document.getElementById('AltMale').checked = true;

Comment: Thanks Ovi - Worked well